# Ensuring consistent UI across 3.5" and 4" devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm almost ready to publish my app, and have one last hurdle to cross. How do I make sure that my user interface will stay the same on both 3.5" and 4" devices? Everything works and looks perfect on the 3.5" simulator. However, some things are not aligned properly on the 4" display. Is there a way I can easily fix this issue? I'm guessing it won't be too difficult since Apple wants to push their new displays. 
Thanks!
~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 0):

Apple's solution is to use Autolayout and Constraints.
See this handy [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) or the Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853) . If you're lucky (and you used Storyboards) then you can probably do it without tremendous effort, but you will have to tweak every individual View.